# Attendance for Minyan on School Shabbaton

Tags: halacha, shabbat, borer-separating

A Jewish day school takes attendance for tefillah on a shabbaton by putting every students’ name on a note card, and then when that person comes to tefillah, their name is taken out of the pile and put in a different pile. For borer to be done on shabbos, one of the conditions is that it must be for immediate use. Is it considered immediate use in this scenario if the immediate use is the actual borer that is being done?

Comment: Other factors to consider: Is this considered a mixture? How is the selection being done; is it a stack, or are all the cards laid out on the table?

Comment: It is a mixture I believe, as the cards are in a stack

Comment: "the immediate use is the actual borer that is being done": I don't see why you say so. Presumably they're taking attendance so as to know later who had attended.

Comment: Right. They will check it later, in which case it is not immediate use, and I would assume that it isn’t allowed. However, what I wasn’t sure about is if the entire goal is to separate something, then is that considered immediate use? In an example of separating food, the purpose is to later eat the good and not the bad. Therefore the immediate separation isn’t a benefit for you, it is preparing for the future. In this case, the action aligns with the goal so does that make a difference?

Comment: @Eman It’s not so simple that it’s a mixture. After all, they’re all the same type of card, so they might be considered one “species” and therefore can’t be called a “mixture” for which separating would apply. On the other hand, they’re all labeled differently, so they might be called several “species.” Let me dig out my Borer notes; IIRC this exact question of whether a deck of cards is a mixture is a dispute between the Rabbis in my Yeshiva, and I want to see if they’re taking sides in an earlier Achronic or Rishonic debate.